# How to provide reproducible Sample Data in Julia

Tags: julia

Here on `stackoverflow.com` - when I provide sample data to make a reproducible example, how can I do it the Julian way?

In `R` for example `dput(df)` will output a string with which you can create `df` again. Hence, you just post the result here on stackoverflow and bam! - reproducible example. So, how should one do it in Julia?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do generally is to simply construct an MWE DataFrame with random numbers etc in your example, so there's no need to read/write out.

In situations where that's inconvenient, you might consider writing out to an IO buffer and taking the string representation of that, which people can then read back in the same way in reverse:

```
julia> using CSV, DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a = rand(5), b = rand(1:10, 5));

julia> io = IOBuffer()
IOBuffer(data=UInt8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1)

julia> string_representation = String(take!(CSV.write(io, df)))
"a,b\n0.5613453808585873,9\n0.3308122459718885,6\n0.631520224612919,9\n0.3533712075535982,3\n0.35289980394398723,9\n"

julia> CSV.read(IOBuffer(string_representation))
5×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a        │ b     │
│     │ Float64  │ Int64 │
├─────┼──────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 0.561345 │ 9     │
│ 2   │ 0.330812 │ 6     │
│ 3   │ 0.63152  │ 9     │
│ 4   │ 0.353371 │ 3     │
│ 5   │ 0.3529   │ 9     │
```

Comment: The following line is missing: `using Random; Random.seed!(0)`. You need to have a fixed seed to ensure reproducibility. [Moreover, it is worth noting that the way random numbers are generated in Julia 1.5 will change and one recommended option is StableRNGs.jl.]

Comment: No, all you need is to read from the `string_representation` as shown.

Comment: I guess generating reproducible random numbers across computers and Julia versions is a slightly different, although related question - I read this question as the simple case of "how do I copy/paste a given DataFrame into SO for a question?", using `rand` in my answer was maybe a distraction...

Comment: I also read it as "how do I copy/paste a given DataFrame into SO for a question?". The other question would "How to create reproducible random numbers in Julia".

Comment: Another note on this: you can't do `CSV.write(io, df)`, `CSV.read(io, DataFrame)`. You need the `IOBuffer` to contain a `String`. You need the intermediate string representation to debug CSV

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to mimic the behaviour of R's `dput` in Julia:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> using Random; Random.seed!(0);

julia> df = DataFrame(a = rand(3), b = rand(1:10, 3))
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a          b
     │ Float64    Int64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │ 0.405699       1
   2 │ 0.0685458      7
   3 │ 0.862141       2

julia> julian_dput(x) = invoke(show, Tuple{typeof(stdout), Any}, stdout, df);

julia> julian_dput(df)
DataFrame(AbstractVector[[0.4056994708920292, 0.06854582438651502, 0.8621408571954849], [1, 7, 2]], DataFrames.Index(Dict(:a => 1, :b => 2), [:a, :b]))
```

That is, `julian_dput()` takes a DataFrame as input and returns a string that can generate the input.

Source: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/given-an-object-return-julia-code-that-defines-the-object/80579/12